# How to add a column in a dataframe using information from another dataframe with different lengths in R?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes with different columns and rows lengths. I want to add two columns in the dataframe A from the dataframe B (columns X and Y) using the "region" column that is present in both dataframes. The figure shows how it looks like and how I would like to get (dataframe C, but can be add to dataframe A as well). I am just showing you the head, but it has a lot of species and the match should be done for all species and the region with x and Y columns. Could someone please help me? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRnnI.jpg)

Comment: check out `dplyr::left_join`

Comment: Welcome. Please share your data.frames using ``dput()`` rather than images, as sharing them as images makes it very difficult for people to help. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `left_join` you won`t get the desired output:

```
data.frame(species=dfA$species, region=dfA$region, X=dfB$X, Y=dfB$Y)
```

```
species <- (rep("Aa achalensis",6))
region <- c("ABT", "AFG", "AGE", "AGS", "AGW", "ALA")
dfA <- data.frame(species, region)

region <- c("ABT", "AGE", "AGS", "AGW", "ALA", "ALB")
LEVEL3_NAM <- c("Alberta", "Argentina Northeast", "Argentina South", "Argentina Northwest", "Alabama", "Albania")
LEVEL2_COD <- c(71, 85, 85, 85,78, 13)
LEVEL1_COD <- c(7,8,8,8,7,1)
X <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Y <- c(7,8,9,10,11,12)
dfB <- data.frame(region, LEVEL3_NAM, LEVEL2_COD, LEVEL1_COD, X, Y)

left_join(dfA, dfB, by="region") %>% 
  select(species, region, X, Y)

data.frame(species=dfA$species, region=dfA$region, X=dfB$X, Y=dfB$Y)
```

With `left_join`

```
       species region  X  Y
1 Aa achalensis    ABT  1  7
2 Aa achalensis    AFG NA NA
3 Aa achalensis    AGE  2  8
4 Aa achalensis    AGS  3  9
5 Aa achalensis    AGW  4 10
6 Aa achalensis    ALA  5 11
```

With `data.frame(species=dfA$species, region=dfA$region, X=dfB$X, Y=dfB$Y)`

```
        species region X  Y
1 Aa achalensis    ABT 1  7
2 Aa achalensis    AFG 2  8
3 Aa achalensis    AGE 3  9
4 Aa achalensis    AGS 4 10
5 Aa achalensis    AGW 5 11
6 Aa achalensis    ALA 6 12
```

Comment: Thank you very much #TarJae!

Comment: OP’s request was to use Region as joining variabile, which doesn’t happen here. Most connections happen “by chance” because the data frames are in the same order. This gets the desired output, however the desired output itself looks off to me. Why would you assign Argentina’s data to Afganistan? That could lead to a serious data quality issue. TarJae, your answer is correct based on the request that is being made, however @Bruna you should check your request again, imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::left_join` to add the columns based on `region` and then use `select` to select only the columns you need.

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe_a %>%
  left_join(dataframe_b, by = "region") %>%
  select(species, region, X, Y)
```

---

There are a lot of ways to join two tables. I'm only showing you one, but you can find more material [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! I do appreciate the suggestions! I am beginner but it will make me learn a lot!! Tks everyone :)